# How can I generate url with random numbers in Flask

Tags: python, flask

Hello guys I am trying to create a url with random numbers but when I try to create it with
random.randint(1,10) or random.randrange(1,10) doesn't seems to work but when I set the variable manually it works perfectly.

```
vartest=random.randint(1,10)

urlsting="/"+str(vartest)

print("urlsting is .......",urlsting)

@app.route(urlsting)
def homeFun():
    return " Congrats!! :-) "
```

When I try to access the created url this Message apperas to the browser

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

But when I use this code I can access it perfectly

```
vartest=7

urlsting="/"+str(vartest)

print("urlsting is .......",urlsting)

@app.route(urlsting)
def homeFun():
    return " Congrats!! :-) "
```

Any suggestions?

I also add the full code as requested

```
from flask import Flask
import random
app= Flask(__name__)


#Doesn't work 
vartest=random.randint(1,10) # or random.randrange(1,10)
#______
#Works perfectly
vartest=7


urlsting="/"+str(vartest)
print("urlsting is .......",urlsting)


@app.route(urlsting)
def homeFun():
    return "Congrats!! :-) "


if __name__=="__main__":    
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port='8888',debug= True)
```

Comment: I can't see any reason why they would work differently. Once you assign `urlsting` it doesn't matter how `vartest` was assigned.

Comment: Do you want to generate a URL for each request? Or just have a different URL everytime the server starts?

Comment: I want to generate a different URL everytime the server starts.

Comment: @Barmar 
I also tried to create a string `import string`  `res = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase +
                             string.digits, k=7))`
`urlsting="/"+res` but it also doesn't seem to work

Comment: It really doesn't matter how you create the URL string. Whatever shows in the `print()` statement should work.

Comment: this works perfectly fine for me.  perhaps show the full code or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

It worked by changing

> debug= False